# VB.net combobox displaying System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

I am trying to return data from an SQL query via Access 2013 into my VB form my code is below.

```
Private Sub frm_8_IncidentResponseSelect_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim query As String = "select ([response ID] &' '&[response date]) As responsedetails from response where [incident id] = " & txt_incidentid.Text & " "
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyDatabase"
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                connection.Open()
                adapter.Fill(dt)
                connection.Close()
              End Using
        End Using
  End Using

    For Each Data As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            cb_responseid.DataSource = dt
            cb_responseid.DisplayMember = "[responsedetails]"
            cb_responseid.ValueMember = "[response id]
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I am being hit with two errors however firstly

VB is returning the following error message

'Cannot bind to the new display member' 
and highlighting the following line of code
  cb_responseid.ValueMember = "[response id]

But also any items in the combox box are returning as System.Data.DataRowView

Can someone show me how/why my code is wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should remove the loop over the rows of your table, just set the DataTable as your DataSource and remove the square brackets around the strings used for the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    cb_responseid.DataSource = dt
    cb_responseid.DisplayMember = "responsedetails"
    cb_responseid.ValueMember = "responseid"
End If
```

Then you need to change your query to return also the `[response id]` field because (after renaming it to something without spaces). Your code use that field to compose a new field called `responsedetails` and thus it is no more visible as a source field to use for the `ValueMember`

```
Dim query As String = "select [response id] as responseid, " & _ 
    " ([response ID] &' '&[response date]) As responsedetails " & _ 
    " from response where [incident id] = " & txt_incidentid.Text & " "
```

Said that, remember that building command text concatenating strings is the worst thing you can do with database programming. You should learn how to use a parameterized query

Another thing that I would change is the use of these fields with spaces in them. They are a very noisy distraction and cause more troubles than they resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is one of the most detailed responses I have had thanks. Going forward in future projects spaces will definitely be taken out of databases as it is nothing but hassle. Thanks again for taking the time to respond.